# Firebase Firestore Parameter 'selected_port[out]' not found in the function declaration warning

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Started seeing this warning on my Xcode while after downloading Firebase Firestore pod and the recommended fix does not actually fix it. What's crazy is it's a warning on a comment.[image: f]

Parameter 'selected_port[out]' not found in the function declaration warning

Comment: Thats not really a problem don't worry about it, if it really bothers you just unlock the file and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6340 that has a fix staged for the upcoming Firebase 6.32.0 release.

In the meantime, it's safe to ignore.